# How to achieve responsive design when using display: flex?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have a problem with the responsive design in bootstrap 3.3.7

This is a row where I have some text in the first column and an image on the second column.

```css
    .portfolio-text {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row portfolio-text">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename="img/advice-public-post.png") }}" class="img-responsive"
                 alt="Advice on public posts">
        </div>
    </div>
```

It looks good on desktop, but on my iPhone I get very small images and the text is fudged next to it.  I would have expected the image and text to be each on a separate row, underneath each other to allow for enough space. You can try my website on your smartphone to see for yourself: http://moodimo.com

Could it be that `display: flex;` is preventing responsive design? What can I do?

Comment: Did you set flex wrap to wrap on the container? Just checked, nope you didn't, add it to `.portfolio-text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add`flex-flow:row wrap`

```css
.portfolio-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;   /* instead of center */  
  flex-flow: row wrap;   /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="row portfolio-text">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 ">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="img-responsive" alt="Advice on public posts">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the attribute `display: flex` from the `portfolio-text` class and bootstrap will take care of it.